# Time complexity of a combination function

Tags: python, python-3.x, big-o, combinations

I have this function that creates pairs from a list of numbers.  We know that there will be a total of n choose 2 iterations every time.  So does that make the time complexity O(nC2)?
or is it O(n^2)?

If it is O(n^2) why is it O(n^2)?  The function does not iterate that many times and it never will.

```
def find_pairs(nums):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        current = nums[i]

        for n in nums[i+1:]:
            pairs.append((current, n))

    return pairs
```

Comment: as `O` is worst case scenario in your case it will be `O(n**2)` reason.. your inner loop will  iterates `(n-1)` for each element `(n)` hence approximately it runs O(n**2) times..!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time complexity isn't about exactly how many times an algorithm is run, it's how the algorithm scales.

In your case n choose 2 is equal to:

```
n! / (2 * (n - 2)!)
```

This can be simplified to

```
n * (n-1) / 2 = (n^2 - n) / 2
```

As you can see we have a 2nd degree polynomial function (quadratic). Therefore we consider the time complexity to be `O(n^2)` since it will scale quadratically.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity for above code is `O(n^2)`
It will iterate 2 times always, both the time on nums,
just after it completes `current = nums[i]` it will iterate again if your secn loop was out of 1st loop i.e something like this

```
def find_pairs(nums):
    pairs = []
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        current = nums[i]

    for n in nums[i+1:]:
        pairs.append((current, n))

    return pairs
```

then time complexity would have been `O(n)`